# List all volumes attached to list of instances using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using `aws-cli` and I need the list of all instance and the volumes associated with them.

```
instance-name,instance-id,volumes-associated
```

`describe-instances` and `describe-volumes` are different way to list instances and volumes. But I need a consolidated list as in the above format.
There could be multiple volumes associated with one instance.

Answer (score 7):

This command will output:

- The value associated with the 'Name' tag
- Instance ID
- EBS Volume ID

  ```
  aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,InstanceId,BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId]' --output text

  i-0d9c9b94b6583af4c
  Database
  vol-629feaa2
  i-3da61da2
  Web B
  vol-a6d443e7
  i-7d264642
  Web A
  vol-7840ce4a
  ```

There might be multiple EBS volumes associated with an instance.

Answer (score 2):

Another example, output is in json format:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Name:ImageId,InstanceId:InstanceId,VolumeInfo:BlockDeviceMappings}' --output json
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case i needed to list all stopped instances and associated volumes for a clean up of cloud resources and cost savings. The following code will do the job for you. If you set it to json output is human friendly.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,InstanceId,BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.VolumeId]' --output text
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this command I can be able to list the volume details with instance id and volume size.

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes –-query "Volumes[*].[Attachments[0].VolumeId,AvailabilityZone,Attachments[0].InstanceId,Attachments[0].State,Size]" --output text > test.txt
```

But my query I have to consolidate the whole instance list its includes instance id, instance state, region, platform, key pair name along with attached volumes name, volume id, volume size and mount path name like   /dev/sda1,

Please help me with this.

Using this command can be able to get the instance details but I need to single query to get all the details.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=*" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`]| [0].Value,InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,Placement.AvailabilityZone,PrivateIpAddress,VolumeInfo:BlockDeviceMappings" --output text > instances.txt
```